# How to increase the plot size in python while using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created some pairplots but cannot seem to increase the area of the plot.The code and the output are shown below for reference.
Please find below a snapshot of the data.
[image]
Can someone please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: quite surprisingly it is not doing anything.The area is not changing at all

Comment: If you can't share your own data, you need to generate random data or use one of the example datasets that are provided for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the size in the [`pairplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) (or other plot) command.

```
plt.figure()
sns.pairplot(attrition_df, size=2.5, aspect=1)
```

`size` equals the height of the facet (subplot) in inches, and the width in inches equals `aspect*size`

Answer (score 2):

`pairplot` has the option `size`, which controls the size, in inches, of each facet.

From the [`pairplot` docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot):

> size : scalar, optional
>
> Height (in inches) of each facet.

Altering this will control the size of the subplots, and also the overall figure size, e.g.

```
sns.pairplot(attrition_df, size=3, ...)
```